# Shortcut key to skip cursor from left/right of every typed word

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

I want to know if it is even possible to jump my cursor from left/right of every typed word using Vimperator, a Firefox addon that behaves like Vim, including its shortcut keys.

So a good example would be:

```
I took a marvelous dump right before bed and I so happen to sleep better.-
```

Now if my cursor is at the end of that sentence (hence the dash) how can I jump my cursor right before the word `better` by just using a shortcut key?

by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> are shortcut keys that brings your cursor to beginning/end of the current line your on.

Comment: `I took a marvelous dump right before bed and I so happen to sleep better.` Yeah, it is indeed comforting to know that your database is backed up.

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.  In most programs that use a cursor, this makes the cursor move by word.

Comment: And in vim it is no different.